# How do I hit Scroll Lock on my keyboard in Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, windows

Somehow, I appear to have Scroll Lock on, which 99% of the time is irrelevant, with the 1% of the time being in Microsoft Excel.  As the keyboard on my MBP (Model 9,2) doesn't acknowledge the existence of this key (or a couple others I often want to use, e.g. Pause, Insert); how can I un-Scroll Lock my keyboard?

Comment: How do you run Windows on your Mac, via Bootcamp or within a VM?

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to emulate Scroll Lock.

Alternatively, Windows 7's On-Screen Keyboard program (search in Start Menu, or find it under Programs, Accessories, then Ease of Access) has a <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> key which you can click to toggle.

Comment: This has been down-voted for reasons that elude me. My similar question had a down-voted answer because people were attempting to use my "in Windows" Q&A to solve their problems on OS X.

Comment: I suspect it's because newer MBP users have touch bars.. The moment you press Fn, the regular F1-F12 in the Touchbar disappear and you get the Siri icon. I wasn't one of the downvoters BTW!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an external keyboard with your MBP? If so (or even if you don't), plug one in, fire up Excel so you can see the option bar at the bottom (to verify everything worked OK), and hit the `F14` key. Alternatively, if you happen to have a PC keyboard handy, just use `Scroll Lock` :)

Comment: No, don't use an external keyboard.